# Python: Pyinstaller on mac current directory problem

Tags: python, operating-system, directory, executable, pyinstaller

I have created a little script that I want to run as an executable on Mac and Windows.

I created the executable as one file using `--onefile` and I want to work with files in the same directory as the executable.

In windows `os.getcwd()` works fine after using `pyinstaller` but on mac it reverts to the base path:

```
> /Users/User
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 93, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/Invoices/'
[62121] Failed to execute script test
logout
```

When I run it as a `.py` file however it gets the right directory on mac as well.

I have tried changing `os.getcwd()` to `os.path.realpath(__file__)` yet it still gives the wrong path when converted with pyinstaller.

I want to be able to move the executable around on mac and work with whatever directory it is in.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the following works:

```
dir_path = slash.join(sys.argv[0].split(slash)[:-1])
```

this works only when using the executable on mac. On windows I still use os.getcwd and when running the python script as well.

Comment: I'm running into this exactly problem on PyInstaller 3.6 and macOS Catalina.  However, when I try your solution, I get the following error: `name 'slash' is not defined`.

I got it to work by substituting `os.path.sep` for `slash` (whatever that is): `os.path.sep.join(sys.argv[0].split(os.path.sep)[:-1])`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found, is:

```
import os, pathlib
import platform

if platform.system() == "Darwin":
    os.chdir(pathlib.Path(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```